# In case of timeout, how to deal with pending socket messages?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to code a program based on sockets to send instruction from an **operator computer** to a **distant computer** the second one sending back answers, so far nothing surprising.

However, certain command might take too much time to be executed or could crash, having the **operator** console waiting forever. For those cases I added a timeout to the socket.

However if the answer finally arrives after the timeout exception get executed, the answer  will be displayed in console when a new command is sent, shifting everything.

My question is simple, how can I kind of remove pending messages if there's any and display correct expected answer ? Or is there any practice I'm not aware of I should use  instead ?

I'm not adding the entire code to save some space and focus on what I believe relevant for my questions but do not hesitate to tell me if more is required;

**operator_computer.py**

```
"""
'distant' is the distant computer socket
"""

def send_message(distant, data):
    jsondata = json.dumps(data)
    distant.send(jsondata.encode())

def recv_message(distant, timeout=30):
    data = ''
    while True:
        distant.settimeout(timeout)
        try:
            data = data + distant.recv(1024).decode().rstrip()
            return "ANSWER: " + json.loads(data)

        except ValueError:
            continue

        except socket.timeout:
            return "ANSWER: TIMEOUT"
```

**distant_computer.py**

```
"""
's' is the socket
"""

def send_message(data):
    jsondata = json.dumps(data)
    s.send(jsondata.encode())

def recv_message():
    data = ''
    while True:
        try:
            data = data + s.recv(1024).decode().rstrip()
            return json.loads(data)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

**This is what it might look like in the operator console**

```
* Shell~: cwd
ANSWER : C:\Users\None\Desktop
----------------------------------------
* Shell~:
ANSWER: Unrecognised command
----------------------------------------
* Shell~: timeout_test
ANSWER: TIMEOUT
----------------------------------------
* Shell~: cwd
ANSWER: Timeout command result
----------------------------------------
* Shell~:
ANSWER : C:\Users\None\Desktop
----------------------------------------
* Shell~: cwd
ANSWER: Unrecognised command
----------------------------------------
* Shell~:
ANSWER : C:\Users\None\Desktop
```

PS : I am new to socket use

Comment: "*how can I kind of remove pending messages if there's any and display correct expected answer ?*" - short answer: you usually can't. If a timeout occurs, the state of the socket is unknown. Unless your messages begin with a unique byte/sequence that you can look for discarding everything received beforehand, usually the best you can do is just reconnect and start over.

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late reply, I had to kind of pause this project. Therefore how would deal any software running on python with this kind of connection ? Webhook or something else ?